# Nth-plicating output -JavaScript

Tags: arrays, loops

I can't perceive the flaw in my tought process in the following snippet.

Basically the 'bug' is that the first input/activity (once I click on the 'Add to List'button) is printed once (as it should be) but the following ones do not. The second activity is printed twice, the third activity is printed 3x and so on...

```
//Target the user input
let theUserInput = document.querySelector('#userInput');

//Target the button
let theAddingButton = document.querySelector('.enter');

//Array to hold all the to-dos that will be pushed into it
let taskList = []
let feedData;

theAddingButton.addEventListener('click', () => {

//Object that will be fed with the user's input
feedData =
{
    "dateEntered": Date(),
    "title": theUserInput.value,
    "statusData": "pending",
},
    // Push the object to the array
    taskList.push(feedData);

//Clean & reset the input field
theUserInput.value = "";
theUserInput.focus();

// Populate the Activity Table
for (let i = 0; i < taskList.length; i++) {

    // Setup the Table Row
    const activityRow = activityTable.insertRow(i + 1);

    // New Cells
    const cell1 = activityRow.insertCell(0);
    const cell2 = activityRow.insertCell(1);
    const cell3 = activityRow.insertCell(2);
    const cell4 = activityRow.insertCell(3);

    // Populate the Cells
    cell1.innerHTML = feedData.title;
    cell2.innerHTML = feedData.dateEntered;
    cell3.innerHTML = feedData.statusData;
    cell4.innerHTML = `<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox" id="title${i + 1}" value="${i}">`;
 }
})
```

My understanding is that:
1-I created an empty array and an object
2-Inside the loop I'll keep pushing the recently created objects inside the array each time it gets clicked.

Can't see what is triggering the additional loops.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You push an entry to the list, then add the _entire list_ to the table. Say tasks are numbers. First click, push 1 to list and render it, HTML has "1". Second click, push 2 to list and render the list _in addition_ to what it had before, and you have "1 1 2". So... either only add the last element to the table (since the previous rows should already be there), or delete the table contents and then write out the entire list, one or the other.

Comment: I see now! Thanks @Amadan! I changed the contents of `cell1.innerHTML= feedData.title` to `taskList[[taskList.length - 1][i]].title;` and it's working now.